# shell script edited on windows displays unexpected error message

Tags: bash, windows, newlines

I am having some trouble running a script to ssh to a remote server. If I simply ssh from the command line I have no trouble reaching the server, but when I run a script to do this I get an error, "Name or service not knownname". I have added the IP address and host name to /etc/hosts and that did not help.

My script is simply:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
ssh username@hostname
```

Am I doing something wrong? Obviously I don't need a script just for this, but I'm going to add commands to execute once I get this working.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: The way you are describing your script makes no sense. You would never type a shebang on the cli directly. Why are you including the `$`s?

Comment: If those `$` really were in the script Daniel would get a different error message. The script should work if the command indeed works in from the command line. Since it doesn't there probably is a typo in the hostname.

Comment: @Jan I'm using ubuntu.
 The $'s aren't part of the script, I just added them because otherwise the first line formats funny, and I've seen other people on here do it.

Comment: @DanielJensen, reedit your question, select the script fragment and click a button above the editor that looks like `{}`, that's how you quote code here.

Comment: @DanielJensen, how do you run the script?

Comment: There isn't a typo. Thats why I'm confused. I run it by typing "bash scriptname" at the command line.

Comment: without a typo the script should work, if the same command works in the interactive shell. unless you're not telling us something.

Comment: Needless to say that this script has not much of a meaning. Did you try to run the script from another terminal?  Does the script work when an IP is used instead? What does  `bash -x script` say ?

Comment: I'm not withholding anything knowingly. I can even just copy the second line and paste it at the command line and it works fine. bash -x script gives me "+ ssh $'username@hostname\r' :Name or service not knownname hostname"

Comment: There you go!. What is `$'username@hostname\r'`  Can you show the script using  `cat -A script` ? Update your question with these details please. Oh and how does your `/etc/hosts` file look like. Especially the entry which holds the hostname

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first question. I don't know where the \r is coming from, it was giving me a different error about that earlier. Yeah, the script prints with cat -A script, with "^M$" at the end of each line.

Comment: not just `\r`, but `$'` and `\r'`, they aren't in your question. Where did they come from?

Comment: Use `sed -e "s/^M//" -i script` or `tr -d \\r <script>script1  and run the script1 again using `bash -x script1`. When copying from Windows to a linux machine you'll get the CR+LF... and the rest of the story is obvious I guess.

Comment: huh, @val0x00ff is correct, bash acts weird if the script uses dos line ends. `dos2unix script` works too, if you have it.

Comment: Oh hey, I got it to work if I use the IP address. I dunno, none of that is in my code, the file is literally just what I have quoted above. @val0x00ff That didn't do anything.

Comment: @DanielJensen are you editing the script in windows? It uses wrong line ends, that's what confuses bash, not the actual commands.

Comment: you can see that if you do `file script`, it would say _script: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators_. That last part is the problem.

Comment: Thats what it is, just figured that out too. Weird that is does that. If I re-write it in Ubuntu it runs fine. Now I know. Thank you guys for helping me figure that out!

Comment: someone should write a formal answer for this one. either @artm

Comment: or @val0x00ff, i guess.

Comment: @val0x00ff has nailed it, to him should be the honor

Comment: @DanielJensen http://webmup.com/BBfEo/  Just created it to demonstrate what was happening! :) Enjoy.

Comment: @val0x00ff, if that was vim you could `:set ff=dos` and `:set ff=unix` to turn it ;-)

Comment: @artm That is correct indeed. I know not much about vim functionality, but that is a great thing to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with the script is that when copying a file from another system like Windows, it adds a newline `\n` and a carriage return `\r\n`. For more about line feeds see [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) entry on wikipedia.

To demonstrate the issue I've uploaded short fragment [here](http://webmup.com/BBfEo/) which explains how to solve the problem.

In short: Use **[tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)** to remove those weird line endings

`tr -d \\r <yourscript>newscript && mv newscript yourscript`

Then run the script again.

Or as artm suggested.

While being in `vim` editor, use

`:set ff=unix`

(**ff** is short for **[fileformat](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format)**) and save the file by `shift+zz`.

Comment: you'd better repeat the solution in plain text here, answers in external links tend to rot away with internet.

Comment: `tr` is fine but requires `mv`. For less typing, use:  `sed -i s/\\r// yourscript`